# ASP.Net save after hyperlink is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement to call a save method, that persists a model/object in the session, when the user leaves the page.

The page has various links that do not raise a postback but just perform a redirect.  Are there any ASP.Net page life cycle methods I can hook into to perform the save without requiring a postback?

Comment: The ASP.NET page lifecycle exists on the server and by definition requires a postback to even get started.  Just use a LinkButton control and redirect from the server-side.

Comment: I kinda thought that, thought there may be some javascript method hidden somewhere that would help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to perform an asynchronous POST request (without waiting for a response) when the window is being unloaded:

An example using jQuery:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.post(location.href, $(document.forms[0]).serialize());
});
```

Although you will probably need to use a slightly different method for Chrome (found on [jQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-unload)):

> It looks like the only way to get the
>   Ajax request to go through in Chrome
>   is to use the non-standard event
>   onbeforeunload. Chrome evidently
>   doesn't wait long enough to send the
>   Ajax request using onunload. It does
>   however wait for alerts...

Comment: I'm not sure, but do we even have access to issue a new request on the unload method?
But cool if it works. For this person he will properbly need to change location.href to the location of the aspx file that can save the values into session.

Comment: It seems that it works. Please read this post on jQuery forums: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-unload

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends.

If you need to save values when the person leaves the page, then thats kinda hard.

What you can do, is to wrap all your links in some jquery, that says like:

- Issue a Ajax Call, to AjaxSave.aspx, then it is completed, then window.location to the links href attribute.

BUT, that will only work if the person clicks on your links, not if the person just closes the browser or something.

You can also take the route to just save the stuff offen, so every time the person issues a post back, you just put the stuff in session. But that will mean that values changed from the last postback to the navigating away from the page is lost - don't know if that is an issue.

The last thing is to do like StackOverflow is doing. If you are editing stuff, it will show a warning when you leave the page, and then you have to click okay, to navigate away from the site.